# The list in my Python program will not work properly

Tags: python, list, class, append

I'm having trouble appending to my list passengers in the code. The error I get is that the list passengers is not defined even though this is defined in the class Buss. Can anyopne help out with this. The next menufunctions are not defined yet so that can wait.

I'm also not sure if I have set the menu loop up right. I'm reallty new to Python and have built this on a code shell that was handed out.

````
import replit
from getkey import getkey, keys


#MENU FUNCTIONS : these are the functions used for the menu

#menuOptions 0
def add_passenger():
  replit.clear()
  passenger_age = int(input("How old is the passenger you wish to add? "))
  print (passenger_age)
  passengers.append(passenger_age)
  input("Press enter to go back")

#menuOptions 1
def print_bus():
  replit.clear()
  print("Here is the age of all passengers")
  input("Press enter to go back")

#menuOptions 2
def calc_total_age():
  replit.clear()
  print("Here is the total age of all passengers")
  input("Press enter to go back")

#defining a class for the passenger list
class Buss:
  passengers = []
  number_of_passengers = 0


#The main part of the program where the menu system is. From here the functions are called.
  def run(self):
    menuOptions = ["Add a passenger\t\t\t\t\t\t\t", "Show the age of all passengers\t\t\t", "Show the total age of all passengers \t", "Exit simulator\t\t\t\t\t\t\t"]
    menuSelected = 0

    while(True):
      replit.clear()
      print("Welcome to MyBusTravels bussimulator, please choose what you want to do:")
      print("\x1b[?25l")

      if menuSelected == 0:
        print(menuOptions[0] + "<--")
        print(menuOptions[1])
        print(menuOptions[2])
        print(menuOptions[3])
      elif menuSelected == 1:
        print(menuOptions[0])
        print(menuOptions[1] + "<--")
        print(menuOptions[2])
        print(menuOptions[3])
      elif menuSelected == 2:
        print(menuOptions[0])
        print(menuOptions[1])
        print(menuOptions[2] + "<--")
        print(menuOptions[3])
      elif menuSelected == 3:
        print(menuOptions[0])
        print(menuOptions[1])
        print(menuOptions[2])
        print(menuOptions[3] + "<--")

      keyPressed = getkey()
      if keyPressed == keys.DOWN and menuSelected + 1 != len(menuOptions):
        menuSelected += 1
      elif keyPressed == keys.UP and menuSelected >= 1:
        menuSelected -=1
      elif keyPressed == keys.ENTER:
        if menuSelected == 0:
          add_passenger()
        elif menuSelected == 1:
          print_bus()
        elif menuSelected == 2:
          calc_total_age()
        elif menuSelected == 3:
          print("\x1b[?25h")
          break


class Program:
  def __init__(self, *args):
    minbuss = Buss()
    minbuss.run()

    replit.clear()
    input("Simulator exited, press Enter to continue . . . ")
    replit.clear()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  my_program = Program()```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now your method `add_passenger()` know nothing about class buss and passenger list in it.

You can pass list as argument

```
def add_passenger(passengers):
```

Then call it

```
if menuSelected == 0:
          add_passenger(self.passengers)
```